# Exclude mac address from home router dhcp (tp-link wd8961)

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

Is there any chance to configure a home router (tp-link wd8961) to exclude a specific MAC address from getting an IP-address via DHCP?

I looked through all settings in the admin UI and through the commands available via telnet, but could not find a thing. So I guess this is already an extremely specific question and I am trying my luck that someone has the necessary information.

One step forward could be if someone knows the directory layout on such a router, since the telnet access allows to edit files, if you know their name.

Background: The MAC address belongs to a gadget that sends measurements to some host on the Internet. The only access I have to the device is to unplug and reconnect its power cord, at which time it will run a  DHCP query. Nmap shows no open ports. I want to tweak the routing for this gadget through my Linux machine to capture its traffic and see what it does. I know how to set up routing and a DHCP server on Linux. I just need to convince the router to keep its hands off this one MAC address. (Re-cabling to connect it to my Linux box directly is currently not an option.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use MAC filtering, which appears to be supported on your router.

http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-322.html

Comment: This would prevent the gadget from getting connected at all, which is not intended. It should only be ignored for dhcp.

Comment: True. You would need to specifically set  a static IP for that device.

Comment: Which I can't, because the only action I can take on it is to pull the power cord.

Comment: @ode2k is correct.  If you want it to get an address but not from DHCP that is the only way.